# How to edit locally a Cocoapods dependencies?

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods

I use Cocoapods on my iOS project to manage dependencies and i keep the `/pod` folder out of my repository as suggested from the Github's `.gitignore` [link](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore#L19-L20)

This raise a problem when a library needs some customization e/o bugfix, because your edited code is not pushed on the repository.

I tried to fork the original repository, create a new podspec and add the new version of the library to the `Cocoapods` repository, but is a very a lot of work.

Any suggestion for a more reliable approach?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a lot of work but forking is the best way forward. If you create a bugfix, then do the right thing and submit a Pull Request on GitHub.

If the project already has a PodSpec in the root, you don't have to create a new one to use your fork.

In your Podfile, include

`pod 'YourLibrary', :git => 'http://github.com/yourname/yourlibrary', :commit => 'shahash'`

Otherwise if you have a local installation you may just point at that

`pod 'YourLibrary', :path => '~/git/yourlibrary'`